# Match Single Array with Multidimentional Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

Sorry but I couldn't figure it out with any answers in stackoverflow, so posting this question. I am trying to match these two arrays - if values $sc is in $sc_array return true.

`$sc = array('Male','3','5','3','1','3','5','26-35');`

```
$sc_array = array(
                    'gender' => array('Male','Female'),
                    'flow' => array("1","2"),
                    'water' => array("5"),
                    'fat' => array("3"),
                    'gene' => array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                    'ankle' => array("3", "4", "5"),
                    'type' => array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                    'age' => array("19-25", "26-35", "36-45", "46-55", "56-70", "71-99")
                    );
```

I am trying to match $sc[0] with $sc_array['gender] ; and so on. Should return true if all of them match else false. Here's what I have done so far that works but with lots of warnings and notices.

```
function find_sc_in_scvalue($sc, $sc_array){
    foreach ($sc_array as $item)
    {   
        $inner_array[] = $item;
            for ($i=0; $i<count($sc); $i++){
                if(in_array($sc[$i], $inner_array[$i])){
                    $result[$i] =  "true";
                }
                else $result[$i] = "false";
            }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

This returns an array showing "true" and "false" properly.
It also shows Undefined offset notice (I found the array_pad solution) and warning about inner_array[$i] not being an array. (I know its not but I don't know how else should I match them?)

Please help me to write a good solution for this. Thanks.

**I provided the perfectly working solution below in the answers.**

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck for over 2 days with this, and I wrote another code just after posting this question here, and it seems to work just fine. Any suggestions to optimize is welcome.

```
$result1 = find_sc_in_scvalue($sc, $sc_array) ? "Match" : "Not Found";

function find_sc_in_scvalue($needle, $haystack){
    foreach ($haystack as $item)
    {   
        $array[] = $item;
    }
    for ($i=0; $i<count($needle); $i++){
        if(in_array($needle[$i], $array[$i])){
            $result[] = "True";
        }
        else $result[] = "False";

    }
    if(in_array("False",$result)){
     return false; 
    } else return true;
}
```